# OpenGL picking performance: ray casting vs. color picking

Tags: opengl, picking

I am curious of how the performance of color picking compares to ray casting. I am looking at the scenario when the mouse is clicked which means only then the scene is rendered in a backbuffer for color picking or ray-cating has to be applied.

Note: I have found this [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80998/3d-picking-for-mouse-move-event) which unfortunatly does not give any indication.

Comment: What would make a satisfactory answer to your question?  Also, have you tried either option and found its performance to be unsatisfactory?

Comment: I have not found unsatisfactory performance for color picking and have never ever implemented ray casting. But I very often find that people use ray casting so I wondered whether this is because of performance (hence this question). A satisfactory answer could be "Reading a framebuffer is so slow that ray-casting calculations is like ~10 times faster" or "generally the performance is similar". I know there is a lot depending on details. Maybe it depends on the case, maybe ray casting is always faster becaue framebuffer reading is a true bottleneck.

Comment: Maybe!  Do you have more details about your particular scenario?

Comment: A possible answer is also: "It highly depends on the scenario, no general statement can be made". This is also satisfactory (if that is the truth). In this case I am really looking for a most general statement. Though I would also be interested in how to answer depends on the case, e.g. what typical things would make one technique faster (and why). To give a scenario specif answer: what would you need to know exactly except from that it is a 3D scene with 3D objects and I want to do picking only on mouse click (not continuously). Would it depend on the number of objects?

Comment: The situation matter so much. The two methodologies have vastly different implications. One example: If the user is to drag across the screen during picking, clearly use a pick buffer. If the user is to only select once, then maybe ray casting is more appropriate.

Comment: As stated in my question the situation is just one simple selection with a mouse-click. The question is how does the performance of color picking and ray-casting typically compare. I did not ask for possible benefits of one technique in other scenarios, though it is an interesting comment. @MickLH Can you be more specific regarding 'ray casting is more appropriate'? Why is it more appropriate?

Comment: Ray casting maintains the same fixed cost with varying screen resolution and field of view settings. Ray casting can query your spatial partitioning scheme with a much simpler intersection geometry (A ray, instead of a trapezoid.) to find meshes which need to processed. I say "more appropriate" because it's able to take better advantage of the known information (Where the user has clicked.) to process less candidate intersections.

Comment: That sounds like a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on multiple factors including...

1. How much geometry you are raycasting against (more = slower)
2. The resolution you are rendering your color picking at (higher = slower)
3. How you've implemented either solution (CPU raycasting? vs GPU color picking? or something else?).
4. Resource constraints -> if your application is already CPU bound, and has plenty of GPU power to spare, doing a super efficient CPU ray cast is still going to be slower than doing an inefficient operation on the GPU.

There is a way to get an answer for your particular situation though - profile it and find out!

It's also important to note, either solution is a reasonable solution in many cases, so going one way or the other is likely not going to be a huge deal.  If you aren't having performance problems, don't spend too much thought trying to choose between reasonable answers IMO!